# R/Python - For Loop Statement for a Trigonometric Formula

Tags: r, python-3.x, numpy, for-loop

I am working on an estimation module, where we are computing seasonality variations and forecasting. Previously, we were using fixed 5-order sinusoidal functions for estimation. The formula was as follows

```
doy_seasonality = exp(z[1]*sin(2*pi*doy/365)+z[2]*cos(2*pi*doy/365)
                       +z[3]*sin(4*pi*doy/365)+ z[4]*cos(4*pi*doy/365)
                       +z[5]*sin(6*pi*doy/365)+ z[6]*cos(6*pi*doy/365)
                       +z[7]*sin(8*pi*doy/365)+ z[8]*cos(8*pi*doy/365)
                       + z[9]*sin(10*pi*doy/365)+ z[10]*cos(10*pi*doy/365))
```

Now, we have tried some modifications in our model. Using Fast Fourier Transform, we are able to generate the orders for trigonometric functions automatically.

For example, on my current dataset, I have the following array of orders.

`order_FFT = [2, 6, 10, 24],` such that

```
order_FFT[0] = 2
order_FFT[1] = 6
order_FFT[2] = 10
order_FFT[3] = 24
```

There will be 4 orders here. With some other dataset, there could be more or less no. of orders. Therefore, I need to define a for loop so that the formula gets modified.

With my current dataset and corresponding orders_FFT array, the for loop should execute the following formula:

```
doy_seasonality = exp(z[1]*sin(2*pi*doy/365)+z[2]*cos(2*pi*doy/365)
                       +z[3]*sin(6*pi*doy/365)+ z[4]*cos(6*pi*doy/365)
                       +z[5]*sin(10*pi*doy/365)+ z[6]*cos(10*pi*doy/365)
                       +z[7]*sin(24*pi*doy/365)+ z[8]*cos(24*pi*doy/365)
```

which basically means

```
doy_seasonality = exp(z[1]*sin(order_FFT[0]*pi*doy/365)+z[2]*cos(order_FFT[0]*pi*doy/365)
                       +z[3]*sin(order_FFT[1]*pi*doy/365)+ z[4]*cos(order_FFT[1]*pi*doy/365)
                       +z[5]*sin(order_FFT[2]*pi*doy/365)+ z[6]*cos(order_FFT[2]*pi*doy/365)
                       +z[7]*sin(order_FFT[3]*pi*doy/365)+ z[8]*cos(order_FFT[3]*pi*doy/365)
```

I am at a loss trying to figure out a for loop code for this. Sorry that I am not able to show my own efforts here.

Comment: What is `z`? Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: z is a list of values. For every order_FFT value, there will be 2 corresponding z-values (one for the sin- part and one for the cos-part).

Comment: What is `doy`? Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: doy stands for day of year. doy values are already passed to the formula from another function.

Comment: I know the abbreviation. What I don't know is if this is a single value or a vector. Note, if you simply provided a minimal reproducible example, I probably would already have answered this question.

Comment: It's a vector, equally spaced, from 1 to 365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use a loop. Here is an R approach:

```
#Some test data
set.seed(42)
z <- rnorm(8)
doy <- 1:365
order_FFT <- c(2, 6, 10, 24)

#separate coefficients for sin and cos in two rows:
z <- matrix(z, nrow = 2)
#calculate the sins and cosins:
sins <- outer(doy, order_FFT, function(x, y) sin(x * pi * y / 365))
cosins <- outer(doy, order_FFT, function(x, y) cos(x * pi * y / 365))
#use matrix products to multiply and sum
doy_seasonality2 <- c(exp(sins %*% z[1,] + cosins %*% z[2,]))
```

Does it produce the same result?

```
doy_seasonality = exp(z[1]*sin(2*pi*doy/365)+z[2]*cos(2*pi*doy/365)
                      +z[3]*sin(6*pi*doy/365)+ z[4]*cos(6*pi*doy/365)
                      +z[5]*sin(10*pi*doy/365)+ z[6]*cos(10*pi*doy/365)
                      +z[7]*sin(24*pi*doy/365)+ z[8]*cos(24*pi*doy/365))
all.equal(doy_seasonality, doy_seasonality2)
#[1] TRUE
```